# Query Parameters vs Template Parameters Azure API Management

Tags: azure-api-management

In Azure API Management, what is the difference between template parameters and query parameters when setting up an API operations?

Answer (score 0):

In Template Parameters, you can add **Description**, **Type** and default **Values**.
[image]

To retrieve the multiple template parameters of different context, you can use query parameters.

```
<set-query-parameter name="name" exists-action="override">
<value>@(context.Request.MatchedParameters["name"])</value>
</set-query-parameter>
```

Reference**:** https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/azure-api-management-use-template-parameters-set-query-anders-eide

Answer (score 0):

A template parameter is always required and is matched when calling the API. If a template parameter is specified and is not mentioned when calling the API, it will result in a response of 404.
Query params in APIM is probably just used for documentation